# What is the purpose of application processor in a wifi module?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessors

I am just learning about embedded systems and checking about wifi modules. I see in the datasheet they mention about a core processor that is integrated with rf SoC. I also see another processor on the MCU called application processor. I am confused about its purpose. What is it used for? Can someone please clarify? For reference, I was reading about the ATSAMW25 module.

Comment: While driving the car are you able to turn a screwdriver on a screw in the fuel injector while sampling the O2 sensors, in your other hand turning a knob on the fuel pressure, and in your other other hand controlling the air coming in (you are already out of hands) etc (need even more hands and eyes).  All at the same time?  Or is it better to have an embedded computer in the car managing the engine, another for heat/cooling another for the radio, another for the gauges, etc...and all you have to do is drive the car?  Similar thing here.

Comment: You are the application, you are in the car, you are making the car go places and do things.  The other things are managing the car to keep it working so you can perform the application.  Some of it may be real-time maintenance, some of it may simply be the various features of the product/technology and a balance between programmable logic and fixed logic in the product, cost/yield, respins, reaction to bugs found down the road, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, devices that include wireless technologies (whether its Bluetooth/BLE, WiFi, LoRa, etc) include both the hardware required to manage the wireless connectivity and then separate hardware for running the higher-level application of the system. Frequently, managing the wireless protocol is intensive enough that it is best done with its own small processor running its own firmware to deal with connectivity and sending data over the link and might include a fair amount of proprietary firmware from the vendor (ie, Microchip in your example). To enable programmers to write their own code for the system, these protocol processors are paired with application processors, ones for whom the development tools and documentation are more openly available to developers for implementing whatever they want to do with the module. By separating the two operations (wireless/protocol and application), the code developers implement has less chance of causing fundamental problems for the wireless connectivity (like, application code hanging causes entire WiFi networks to fail) and the proprietary aspects of the system can be better protected (or another way, more documentation can be provided to developers without signing an NDA as the application processor is more "open" while the details of the wireless implementation are usually not).

In the case of the module youre looking at, the wireless hardware is all inside the ATWINC1500 and is accessed via SPI and some other GPIO by the SAMD21G (the application processor). All the code you write for the module end up running on the SAMD21G with some library/driver support to implement the wireless functions (which under the hood, are implemented by talking to the ATWINC1500). The ATWINC1500 simply runs the code the vendor (Microchip) wrote to actually do all the wireless protocol work and provides an interface for another processor (in this module, the SAMD21G) to control it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It clarifies quite a lot of things for me. So if I don't want to use the application processor SAMD21G, can I use something like an Arduino board with the same ATSAMW25 module?

Comment: @user6053898 You could, though youd need to put firmware on the application processor to expose some kind of interface between the Arduino board and the module. Sometimes, modules like this have premade firmware from the vendor that exposes something like an AT command interface for the module (like how Espressif does for their ESP32/ESP8266 modules), though I wasnt able to find it from Microchips website with a quick search. Alternatively, you can run your sketch directly on the application processor (thats what its for after all!) and it seems like there are Arduino boards using the SAMD21G.

Comment: Not just wireless, you can/will see this in wired phys as well, typically 8051s or z80s due to lack of royalties those are the popular ones I see on a regular basis (yes your computer might have an 8051 or z80 that someone is maintaining code for).  It is often easier to put some sort of processor or state machine in a part vs re-spinning the part to make changes which is very expensive.  So there is a balance between programmability for managing the complicated thing vs pure logic. then somewhere you want the application to run, integration into the same chip is not uncommon.